# Export beforeAll and afterAll in JEST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

There are some files I am repeating this pattern:

```
beforeAll(() => {
    MockDate.set(1487076708000)
 })

  afterAll(() => {
    MockDate.reset()
 })
```

The only thing I am doing here, is to mock the date. I am wondering if there's a way to export into a helper these methods and then invoke it in the needed files.

Global beforeAll wouldn't work for me since I just need it for 4 or 5 files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply encapsulate them in a function you will import and call. Here a working example:

*helpers/init.js*

```
module.exports = function() {
    beforeAll(() => {
        MockDate.set(1487076708000)
    })

    afterAll(() => {
        MockDate.reset()
    })
}
```

*suite.spec.js*

```
const init = require('./helpers/init')

describe("block", () => {
    init()

    it("test", () => {
    })
})
```

Comment: Very valid point. I thought on that, but was wondering if it was a kind of jest way to make it. Anyway, I'll go for this :) Thanks!